# Calling any endpoint redirects to the login page in Spring Boot Web Flux application

Tags: java, spring-security, amazon-cognito, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I am facing an issue with Spring Security, namely, I can log in to the application but when trying to call any endpoint different than the default login URL `/` my application redirect me to the Cognito login page. My `WebSecurityConfiguration` looks like:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:security.properties")
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

  public static final String ADMIN_LOGIN_URL = "/auth/login";
  public static final String USER_LOGIN_URL = "/auth/loginUser";
  public static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/auth/signOut";
  public static final String SIGNUP_BY_ADMIN_URL = "/auth/signUp";
  public static final String SIGNUP_URL = "/registration";
  public static final String API_DOCS_URL = "/v2/api-docs";
  public static final String NUTRITION_URL = "/nutrition/api/**";
  public static final String OAUTH2_URL = "/oauth2/**";
  public static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
  public static final String DEFAULT_URL = "/";
  public static final String OAUTH2_LOGIN_URL = "/login**";
  public static final String OAUTH2_WILDCARD_URL = "/oauth2/**";
  public static final String WHO_AM_I_URL = "/who";

  private final ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Object> reactiveRedisTemplate;

  public WebSecurityConfiguration(
      @Qualifier("reactiveWhitelistingRedisTemplate")
          ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Object> reactiveRedisTemplate) {
    this.reactiveRedisTemplate = reactiveRedisTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) {

    return httpSecurity
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(OAUTH2_URL, WHO_AM_I_URL, SIGNUP_URL)
        .permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .and()
        .build();
  }
}
```

`application.yml` looks like:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            client-id: XXX
            client-secret: XXX
            scope: openid
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito
            clientName: fitnesstest
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_XXX
```

My `RoutingHandler` looks like:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RoutingHandlers {

  private final CognitoAuthenticationService authService;

  public Mono<ServerResponse> signUpUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    Mono<UserSignUpRequest> signUpRequestDto = serverRequest.bodyToMono(UserSignUpRequest.class);

    var signUpResult = authService.signUpUser(signUpRequestDto);
    return ServerResponse.status(201)
        .body(fromPublisher(signUpResult, UserSignUpResponse.class))
        .onErrorResume(
            e ->
                ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(e.getMessage())));
  }
}
```

with `RouterConfiguration`

```
@Component
public class ApiGatewayRouterConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction(RoutingHandlers routingHandlers) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(
        POST("/register").and(accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)), routingHandlers::signUpUser);
  }
}
```

I tried to split `pathMatcher`'s, comment-out

```
.anyExchange().authenticated()
```

but with this approach after a login attempt, I am receiving 403.

Will be grateful for suggestions on how to fix this issue. Cheers!

EDIT
Typical material fatigue...
It seems that with small tweaks in `WebSecurityConfiguration`
it's working fine:

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) {

    return httpSecurity
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(OAUTH2_URL, WHO_AM_I_URL, SIGNUP_URL)
        .permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .and()
        .build();
}
```

and wrong URL here:

```
public static final String SIGNUP_URL = "/register";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have an artifact "spring-boot-starter-security" included in your pom, this leads to the login page redirects.